# When can closedness of a constructible set be checked using DVRs?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $S$ a Noetherian scheme and $X \subseteq |S|$ be a constructible subset of its topological space defined by some point-wise property $P$. To check whether $X$ is closed, it suffices to show that the property $P$ is stable under specialization, which reduces to checking the same condition on specializations of height 1. That is, we may reduce to the case that $S = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a 1-dimensional, local Noetherian ring.

Often, in the literature, I see arguments now assume that **$S$ is a DVR.** This reduction corresponds to assuming that $S$ is regular. *Why can one make this reduction?* There are many examples inside of affine space of height one specializations that do not give rise to DVRs, e.g. the stalk at a singularity on a curve.

An example can be found in Conrad's [reductive group schemes](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf), the proof of Proposition 3.1.12. Brian is generally a careful guy, so I assume the reduction is valid, but I haven't found a justification for this in e.g. EGA IV3.9.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, but I think in the proof of Proposition 3.1.12 one argues that the property $P$ behaves nicely under preimages, and then one can take your scheme $S$, reduce to the one dimensional case, take a desingularization, see that your locus is closed there, and argue that since the desingularization map is proper, it was closed before taking the desingularization too. It's not obvious to me that one can always assume that $S$ is a DVR in the setting of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey Guminov in the comments is correct - it won't literally be the case that if $s_0\rightsquigarrow s_1$ is a specialization in $S$, then $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{s_0},s_1}$ is a DVR. But what is true is that there exists a morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\to S$ where $A$ is a DVR and the images of the generic and special point are $s_0,s_1$ respectively. For reference, Hartshorne exercise II.4.11(a) lays out how to prove it:

> **Exercise II.4.11.** If you are willing to do some harder commutative algebra, and stick to noetherian schemes, then we can express the valuative criteria of separatedness and properness using only *discrete* valuation rings.
>
> (a) If $\mathcal{O},\mathfrak{m}$ is a noetherian local domain with quotient field $K$, and if $L$ is a finitely generated field extension of $K$, then there exists a discrete valuation ring $R$ of $L$ dominating $\mathcal{O}$.
> Prove this in the following steps.
> By taking a polynomial ring over $\mathcal{O}$, reduce to the case where $L$ is a *finite* extension field of $K$.
> Then show that for a suitable choice of generators $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ of $\mathfrak{m}$, the ideal $\mathfrak{a}=(x_1)$ in $\mathcal{O}'=\mathcal{O}[x_2/x_1,\cdots,x_n/x_1]$ is not equal to the unit ideal.
> Then let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a minimal prime ideal of $\mathfrak{a}$, and let $\mathcal{O}'_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the localization of $\mathcal{O}'$ at $\mathfrak{p}$.
> This is a noetherian local domain of dimension $1$ dominating $\mathcal{O}$.
> Let $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}'}_{\mathfrak{P}}$ be the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}'_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $L$.
> Use the theorem of Krull-Akizuki (see Nagata [7, p. 115]) to show that $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}'}_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is noetherian of dimension $1$.
> Finally, take $R$ to be a localization of $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}'}_{\mathfrak{P}}$ at one of its maximal ideals.

Here's the Krull-Akizuki theorem referenced above:

> **Theorem.**: Let $A$ be a reduced noetherian ring of dimension at most one with $K$ its ring of fractions.
> If $B$ is a subring of a finite extension $L$ of $K$ containing $A$, then $B$ is a one-dimensional noetherian ring.
> Furthermore, for every nonzero ideal $I$ of $B$, the quotient $B/I$ is finite over $A$.

This gets you the required $f$ and $A$, and now (assuming your condition plays nicely with base change) you can really assume that $S$ is the spectrum of a DVR.

Comment: Isn't this just a really roundabout way to avoid talking about the normalization? The normalization map is integral, so the two should have the same dimension. And certainly it is still Noetherian. Normal implies regular in codimension 1, so the result is regular. So pick any point over the closed point and localize there to obtain a regular local Notherian integral domain, i.e. a DVR, equipped with a surjection onto Spec O?

Comment: Is the Hartshorne construction giving something more? Is my argument above hiding some hard commutative algebra?

Comment: Normalization doesn't preserve the property of being noetherian - take the normalization of $\Bbb Z$ in $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, for instance.